# Converting values to fit in an Image

Tags: php

I have to read out some values from a database and create a line diagram with it.

The values i get from the database are the time in ms(going up to 72000) for the x-axis, and a value between 0 and 10 for the y-axis.

How do I get the values ranging from 0 to 72000 into the picture which has to have a width of 800px and how do use the complete 600px of the y-axis with the 0-10 values?

Comment: Junior school arithmetic?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Cross-Multiply

Comment: Some simple scaling it sound like